# Unable to establish Oracle enterprise connection using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, oracle-dbms

When I run the following command

```
sqlplus user/mysecretpass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=10.1.250.81)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=gisdb)))
```

I am able to establish connection and result is as follows

[image]

I am also able to connect to same database using SQL Developer but when I try to create database connection from ArcMap 10.6.1 I get the following error

[image]

I have also followed the [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/How_to_install_Oracle_Client_in_order_to_create_an_ArcGIS_connection_with_an_enterprise_database?lang=en) here, but I am unable to solve this issue. Can anyone let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: There are a number of potential causes, but the most likely is not having the required environment variables. If you use the ArcPy equivalent function you might get a more explicit error. Either way, we need more than you've provided to help.

Comment: In the ArcGIS connection string, you say `10.1.250.81/gisdb` `gisdb` is a *service* name. In your command line sqlplus, `gisdb` is a *sid*. The best connection method is to always use service names. What happens when you do `sqlplus user/mysecretpass@10.1.250.81:gisdb` then `sqlplus user/mysecretpass@10.1.250.81/gisdb` ? Do both work ?

Comment: Forgot this to clarify: a `/` in the connection string means that whatever follows is a service name. a`:`means that what follows is a "sid" or "system ID". A "sid" identifies a physical database "instance" (= the processes that access a database). A clustered database can have multiple such instances, on multiple servers: each has its own SID. On the other hand, all instances can share the same service. This is how applications can automatically failover to a different server.

Comment: Using a service name is the proper way to connect to a database. It is the **only** way when you connect to a multi-tenant environment (and this is the default now for all Oracle databases, including XE). It is also the only way to connect to a cloud-served database.

Comment: Hi Godfrind, when I try to run user/mysecretpass@10.1.250.81/gisdb it gives me TNS:Listener does not know of service requested in connect descriptor and when I try sqlplus user/mysecretpass@10.1.250.81:gisdb I get connect failed because target host or object does not exist.

Comment: So that means your database does not expose service `gisdb`. Can you do `SQL> select name,network_name from all_services;` to see what services it exposes ? (you need to do this as `sys` or `system`). It may be that it exposes a fully-qualified service name - like `gisdb.company.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the following entry in tnsnames.ora

```
test =(DESCRIPTION=ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=10.1.250.81)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=gisdb)))
```

and then using the specified tnsname "test" as instance while connecting to oracle from ArcMap.